# DontDestroyOnLoad Is not working propley and Repeat Screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

**I was tried to save score value paramently** and  and i use the DontDestroyonLoad()  here is the code

```
void Start()
    {
        //DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
        LoadPlayerProgress ();
    }
```

**and  When i move back on other  screen It give this**
**These buttons are part of** **DontDestroyonLoad screen .**.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Edit your question to make it clear: how do you expect it to work and what do you have instead

Answer (score 0):

You provided little to no information, but from experience, I can tell you that if you are using a UI element as a score holder and you are not calling DontDestroyOnLoad() on canvas that holds that UI element, your element will disappear or act strangely. PS. I would post this as a comment but the reputation system doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `DontDestroyOnLoad()` keeps all the things like gameobjects, scripts or component, that's why you are seeing those buttons which are not part of your current scene.

Second thing is use `PlayerPrefs`. It used to save information locally as `int`, `float` and `string`. Read official docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).